# L = { u#w | u != w} context-free

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

So i am trying to proove that  L = { u#w | u != w } (from {a,b}* ) is not a contex-free language.

With the pumping lemma i tried a^p # a^r , but how can i pump so they would become equal.

Or can I get it from {w#w| w in {a,b}* } (since we know it's not a contex-free language) using only contex-free operations (union, concatenation ...)
Any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is context free.

We have two cases: $|u| \neq |w|$ or $u = p m q$ and $v = r n s$ for some strings $p, q, r, s$ s.t. $|p| = |r|$ and $m, n \in \{a, b\}$, $m \neq n$.

Language $\{u\#w|\ |u|\neq |w|\}$ is generated by grammar ($S$ is starting non terminal)
$$C \to a|b$$
$$S \to L | R$$
$$L \to CL|CE$$
$$R \to RC|EC$$
$$E \to \# | CEC$$
($C$ generates single symbol, $L$ generates words with more symbols before $\#$ than after, $R$ with more symbols after $\#$ and $E$ with equal number of symbols)

Language $\{u\#w | u = pmy, v=qrs, m \neq n, |p|=|q|\}$ is generated by
$$C \to a|b$$
$$D \to CD | \varepsilon$$
$$S \to AbD | BaD$$
$$A \to CAC|aD\#$$
$$B \to CBC|bD\#$$
($D$ generates all words, $A$ generates words of form $p b q \# r$ where $|p| = |r|$ and $B$ generates words of form $p a q \# r$)

It's essentially CFG version of [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/42305/14993) answer on cs.se by @babou.